# Multiple Tabs Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bt4f8zk/

Basically, I'm trying to have multiple tabs working, and for the most part, they are.

However, for some reason, when clicking on a new tab on the second one (for example), it replicates the content in the first, even though it should only work on the second.

My jQuery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).data("tab");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hptbqLdv/) with following adjustments:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");   
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).data("tab");
    $(this).closest(".tabs-container").find(".tab-content").
            not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

and also adjusted the `data-tab` values for the second `tabs-container` to avoid doubles.

The main adjustment was to change

```
$(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
```

into

```
$(this).closest(".tabs-container").find(".tab-content").
            not(tab).css("display", "none");
```

so changes on one tabs-container only affects the current and not both.

For the CSS I've added the renamed `.tab-4` (first tab of the second tabs-container) to

```
.tab-1, .tab-4 {
   display: block;
}
```

so the first tabs of both containers are displayed initially.